# How to "unset" element from within iteration

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

How can I unset the current element from this "elems" array if it meets a certain condition?

```
var elems = $('input, select, textarea', this);

elems.each(function(){

  if($(this).attr('name') == 'something') {
    // unset `this` from elems ??
  }

});
```

I did a console.log on it and it doesn't appear to have keys...

Comment: well I mean remove it from the array, like unset in PHP :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the `filter()` function, which constructs a new jQuery object of those which returned `true` from the predicate function.

```
var elems = $('input, select, textarea', this);

elems = elems.filter(function(){

  if($(this).attr('name') == 'something') {
    return false;
  }

  return true;

});
```

This could of course then become;

```
var elems = $('input, select, textarea', this).filter(function(){
  if($(this).attr('name') == 'something') {
    return false;
  }

  return true;
});
```

For more info, see the [`filter()` docs](http://api.jquery.com/filter).

Comment: change to `return $(this).attr('name') != 'something'` and it's perfect.

Answer (score 6):

You should do this within the initial selector instead:

```
var elems = $('input, select, textarea', this).not('[name="something"]');
```

Comment: @Alex GIGO :)                       .

Answer (score 3):

```
elems.filter(function(){
    return $(this).attr('name') !== 'something';
});
```

That will reduce the collection of elements to those whose name attribute isn't "something" (said another way: If the name attribute *is* "something", the element will be filtered out)